# How to force using a lower version python library in Databricks

Tags: python, pip, databricks

I am trying to use huggingface `transformers` in Databricks runtime 13.3. However current version of transformers can't be imported because it conflicts with the version of `urllib3` (2.1.0) that is preinstalled on the cluster. A lower version would work with `transformers`. However according to Databricks, none of the libraries that comes with the runtime can be uninstalled.

I tried something like [image: this], but it doesn't let me switch. What is the correct way to force using lower version of a lib on Databricks

Answer (score 0):

Use `%pip install` to update `urllib3` version on your notebook:

```
%pip install urllib3==1.26
```

for more details see [Notebook-scoped Python libraries](https://docs.databricks.com/en/libraries/notebooks-python-libraries.html)

Comment: If I do this, there will be two versions of urllib3 on the cluster, 2.1 and 1.26. We are not import urllib3 because `transformers` implicitly calls urllib3. And urllib3 2.1 is the system default, it won't use urllib3 1.26